# mostrar página html em php

Tags: php, html

Estou fazendo um código em php, após esse código realizar sua ação gostaria de mostrar outra página em html ex:

```
echo " <a href= 'main.html' > ";
```

aí iria aparecer a página `<main.html>`.
Porém não sei como e nem se possível... Gostaria de uma ajuda ou indicação de como faze-lo.

Comment: E qual seria essa ação? Note bem que os headers não poderão ser enviados se essa ação for output.

Answer (score 1):

conforme já mencionado, headers não podem ser enviados após o output,
então se você não realiza nenhum output, poderá usar essa função para redirecionar para outra página :

```
header('Location: main.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

A tag `<a>` do HTML é comumente utilizada para construír links: `<a href="example.com>Exemplo</a>`, e não para "mostrar" outra página HTML.

A solução mais simples para resolver este problema é utilizando a função `include()` do PHP:

```
<?php
include("minhapagina.html");
?>
```

Esta função irá buscar o conteúdo dessa página e incluir o mesmo na página atual. A utilização de um `header()` iria apenas redirecionar o utilizador, aderindo ao facto que headers não podem ser enviados após output.

Comment: `include("minhapagina.html");`

Answer (score -5):

Se vc quer fazer a imagem aparecer e vc está usando banco de dados... eu sei como fazer.. o teu echo tem de ser assim:

```
$busca_query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE colunanoBD = '$busca'");
while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($busca_query)) {
echo "<img src='Visual/imagens/$dados[foto]' /></b><br/></a>";
```

neste caso o Visual é pasta e dentro esta a pasta imagem e la no bd na coluna vc poem a imagem assim > foto.jpg < so isto... so a imagem com extensao.

Se vc quiser bota uma `div` antes do `<?php`.  Você pode botar um style e movimentar com `margin left` center ou right a vontade pela tela a foto.